# How to Prevent Content in a Container From Overlapping Text in the Background Image?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a hero section that plays a video in the background and over the top of that is an image that contains transparent text towards the top, creating an affect where you can see the video playing through the letters.

I need to add additional content to that section over the top of the background image and I want to ensure that the content does not ever overlap the section of the background image that has the text, regardless of the screensize.

How would I do that with CSS / SASS?

Here is the code I have so far (I haven't added the additional content to the section yet):

HTML / Twig:

```
{% set backgroundVideo = block.backgroundVideo.one %}
{% set backgroundImage = block.coverImage.one %}
<section class="hero" style="background-image: url('{{ backgroundImage.getUrl }}')">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <video playsinline autoplay muted loop class="hero__bg-video">
        <source src="{{ backgroundVideo.getUrl }}" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

SASS:

```
.hero {
  height: 700px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  &__bg-video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyway you could add a codepen or fiddle as an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Can't really spin up a codepen or fiddle for this but here's a codepen built by someone else that is a pretty good example: https://codepen.io/pbreen/pen/dNqoZq

What I'm trying to build is pretty similar in that it has a background image but imagine that the "page title" text is implemented via a background image that spans the entire container and the "page title" portion of it is transparent.

Basically, I want to add content over that background image (h2, p tag, etc.) but I want to make sure that content always stay below / never overlaps the "page title" text in the background image.

Comment: Why couldn't you create a codepen? Just use/post the generated HTML